# How to read tmpfs as a block device in linux?

Tags: linux, dd, imaging, tmpfs, block-device

A typical linux machine mounts a `tmpfs` to store temporary files:

```
$ df
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             953M  702M  203M  78% /
tmpfs                 1.5G  111M  1.5G   0% /tmp
...
```

On a live machine, how can I access the underlying memory of the `tmpfs` as a block device in order to image it with `dd` for file recovery / forensic / intrusion detection purposes? There is no device in `/dev` that properly isolates and maps the memory used by the `tmpfs` to a block device.

This question has been asked here, but none of the answers were helpful: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-backup-ramfs-or-tmpfs-using-dd-4175422520/

Comment: *"how can I access the underlying memory of the `tmpfs` as a block device"* -- You cannot; memory has no *"block"* interface.  *"There is no device in `/dev`"* -- Because memory is not a *"device"*.

Comment: @sawdust Well, there is [/dev/kmem](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html). But that's all of the kernel virtual memory, not just tmpfs.

Comment: `tmpfs` is not based on any flat block device in the first place, and it has no file system compatible with any such block device, so there is nothing to 'image'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what Ive read there is no underlying block device. tmpfs is dynamically resized through the kernel - from which I deduce it cant be treated as a block.  Ypu wpld need to use ramdisk of you want a block device.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm guessing the original question is impossible without messing with custom kernel modules or the kernel itself...

Comment: ramfs works identically to tmpfs (except for it being locked into physical memory, while tmpfs can be swapped out). It's _ramdisk_ (brd) that provides a block device.

Comment: @user1686 Ive updated my answer. It wmbarrasing it received upvotes while being wrong.  Thank you!